# GCC: Wrong compile-time evaluation of __builtin_ctz in some situations with -O2 and -O3

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I have been debugging a strange issue in the past hours that only occured in a release build (-O3) but not in a debug build (-g and no optimizations). Finally, I could pin it down to the "count trailing zeroes" builtin giving me wrong results, and now I wonder whether I just found a GCC bug or whether I'm missing something.

The short story is that apparently, GCC evaulates `__builtin_ctz` wrongly with -O2 and -O3 *in some situations*, but it does fine with no optimizations or -O1. The same applies to the long variants `__builtin_ctzl` and `__builtin_ctzll`.

My initial assumption is that `__builtin_ctz(0)` should resolve to 32, because it is the `unsigned int` (32-bit) version of the builtin and thus there are 32 trailing zero bits. I have not found anything stating that these builtins are undefined for the input being zero, and practical work with them has me convinced that they are not.

Let's have a look at the code I'd like to talk about now:

```
bool test_basic;
bool test_ctz;
bool test_result;

int ctz(const unsigned int x) {
    const int q = __builtin_clz(x);
    test_ctz = (q == 32);
    return q;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {
        const int q = __builtin_clz(0U);
        test_basic = (q == 32);
    }
    {
        const int q = ctz(0U);
        test_result = (q == 32);
    }
    
    std::cout << "test_basic=" << test_basic << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test_ctz=" << test_ctz << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test_result=" << test_result << std::endl;
}
```

The code basically does three tests, storing the results in those boolean values:

1. `test_basic` is true if `__builtin_clz(0U)` resolves to 32.
2. `test_ctz` is true if `__builtin_clz(x)` equals 32 within the function `ctz`.
3. `test_result` is true if the result of `ctz(0)` equals 32.

Because I call `ctz` once in my `main` function and pass zero to it, I expect all three bools to be true by the end of the program. This actually is the case if I compile it without any optimizations or `-O1`. However, when I compile it with `-O2`, `test_ctz` becomes false. I consulted the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to find out what the hell is going on. (Note that I am using g++ 7.5 myself, but I could reproduce this with any later version as well. In the Compiler Explorer, I picked the latest it has to offer, which is 10.2.)

Let's have a look at the code [compiled with -O1](https://godbolt.org/z/qPsa5e) first. I see that `test_ctz` is simply set to 1. I guess that's because these builtins are treated as `constexpr` and the whole rather simple function `ctz` is evaluated at compile-time. The result is correct (under my initial assumption) and so I'm fine with that.

So what could possibly go wrong from here? Well, let's look at the code [compiled with -O2](https://godbolt.org/z/5o3f3x). Nothing much has changed, just that `test_ctz` is now set to 0! And that's that, beyond any logic: the compiler apparently evaluates `q == 32` to being false, but then `q` is returned from the function and we compare that against 32, and suddenly it's true (`test_result`). I have no explanation for this. Am I missing something? Have I found some demonical GCC bug?

It gets even funnier if you `printf` the value of `q` just before `test_ctz` is set: the console then prints 32, so the computation actually works as expected - at runtime. Yet at compile-time, the compiler thinks `q` is not 32 and `test_ctz` is forced to false. Indeed, if I change the declaration of `q` from `const int` to `volatile int` and thus force the computation at runtime, everything works as expected, so luckily there's a simple workaround.

To conclude, I'd like to note that I also use the "count leading zeroes" builtins (`__builtin_clz` and long versions) and I could not observe the same problem there; they work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have not found anything stating that these builtins are undefined for the input being zero

How could you missed it??? From [gcc online docs other builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fclz):

> Built-in Function: int __builtin_ctz (unsigned int x)
>
> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit position. **If x is 0, the result is undefined.**

> So what could possibly go wrong from here?

Code behaving differently with different optimizations levels in 99% of cases is a clear indication of undefined behavior in your code. In this case the compiler optimizations makes different decisions then architecture instruction [BSR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr) and in case the compiler generates the `BSR` on x86 architecture, the result is *still* undefined, from the link `If the content source operand is 0, the content of the destination operand is undefined`. Och, there's also [LZCNT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lzcnt) in which case you'll get `LZCNT will produce the operand size when the input operand is zero`, which maybe better explains the behavior of your code.

> Am I missing something?

Yes. You are missing that `__builtin_ctz(0)` is undefined.

> Have I found some demonical GCC bug?

No.

> I'd like to note that I also use the "count leading zeroes" builtins (__builtin_clz and long versions) I could not observe the same problem there; they work just fine.

Can be seen in gcc docs that `__builtin_clz(0)` is also undefined behavior.

Comment: OK I am honest here, I don't know how I could miss that. Many thanks.

Comment: By now I realized how I missed it: (1) I assumed it was just LZCNT, which, as you said, produces the operand size if the input is zero - exactly what I needed - and (2) I was only ever really interested in the long versions, but the note that the builtin is not defined for 0 is only given for the unsigned int versions. The description of the long versions just refers to those and frankly, I didn't read that. For my minimal example, I chose to use that core version nonetheless. So yeah, this is a classic case of RTFM, but at least it seems I can defend myself somewhat. :-)